# NoSuchMethodError (NoSuchMethodError: Class 'bool' has no instance method '[]'. Receiver: true Tried calling: []("title"))

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

```
 Future<void> fetchAndsetProduct() async {
    final url =Uri.parse( 'https://shoppingapp-ef04b-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/product.json');
    try {
      final response = await http.get(url);
      final extractedData = json.decode(response.body) as Map<String, dynamic>;
      final List<Product> loadedProducts = [];
      extractedData.forEach((prodId, prodData) {
        loadedProducts.add(Product(
          id: prodId,
          title: prodData['title'],
          description: prodData['description'],
          price: prodData['price'],
          isFavorite: prodData['isFavorite'],
          imageUrl: prodData['imageUrl'],
        ));
      });
      _items = loadedProducts;
      notifyListeners();
    } catch (error) {
      throw (error);
    }
  }
```

Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: Class 'bool' has no instance method '[]'.

I was trying to solve this problem, But I am unable to do that

Answer (score 0):

just print your prodData and check is there is any data in your title or not

```
     extractedData.forEach((prodId, prodData) {
print('prodData  $prodData');
print('prodData['title'] $prodData['title']');

        loadedProducts.add(Product(
          id: prodId,
          title: prodData['title'],
          description: prodData['description'],
          price: prodData['price'],
          isFavorite: prodData['isFavorite'],
          imageUrl: prodData['imageUrl'],
        ));
      });
```